# Runtime error referencing a resource in string.xml

Tags: android

I am getting a Java runtime exception when I reference a resource from string.xml.  I read "String Resources" and "Accessing Resources" on the Android developer website and still don't know why these are wrong.  Thanks so much for your help!

In string.xml:

```
    <string name="fAudioRecorderDir">AudioRecorder</string>
```

In Java: (this is line 26 of upload that got NullPointerException)

```
 final String homeDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" + getResources().getString(R.string.fAudioRecorderDir) + "/";
```

> ### From Logcat ##

```
E/AndroidRuntime(14597): FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
E/AndroidRuntime(14597): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.medikin.android.dictaphone/com.medikin.android.dictaphone.Upload}: java.lang.NullPointerException  
E/AndroidRuntime(14597):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)  
E/AndroidRuntime(14597):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1487)  
E/AndroidRuntime(14597):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)  
E/AndroidRuntime(14597):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)  
E/AndroidRuntime(14597):    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:654)  
E/AndroidRuntime(14597):    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:326)  
E/AndroidRuntime(14597):    at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:132)  
E/AndroidRuntime(14597):    at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:456)  
E/AndroidRuntime(14597):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)  
E/AndroidRuntime(14597):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)  
E/AndroidRuntime(14597):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)  
E/AndroidRuntime(14597):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)  
E/AndroidRuntime(14597):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)  
E/AndroidRuntime(14597):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)  
E/AndroidRuntime(14597):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  
E/AndroidRuntime(14597):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)  
E/AndroidRuntime(14597):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)  
E/AndroidRuntime(14597):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)  
E/AndroidRuntime(14597):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  
E/AndroidRuntime(14597): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException  
E/AndroidRuntime(14597):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:80)  
E/AndroidRuntime(14597):    at com.medikin.android.dictaphone.Upload.<init>(Upload.java:26)  
E/AndroidRuntime(14597):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)  
E/AndroidRuntime(14597):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)  
E/AndroidRuntime(14597):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)  
E/AndroidRuntime(14597):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)  
E/AndroidRuntime(14597):    ... 18 more  
W/ActivityManager(   68):   Force finishing activity com.medikin.android.dictaphone/.Dictaphone
```

Comment: Seems ok. Try to `Log.d(homeDir)` to be sure and, _please_, could you point the line where the Exception appear and what the exception was? (In case you do not know: just launch `adb logcat` in a shell)

Comment: OK, here is what I get from Logcat:

Comment: sorry about the mix up.  Logcat is together w/ the code now.

Comment: It seems it's a NullPointerException at line 26 of Upload.java. Is that the line in your question?

Comment: yes, the Java code in the question is line 26.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here but I'm giving it a try anyway (you should add more of your code):

- getRessources fails when it tries to get its context, I think that's because your class does not herit from a context (a separate helper class maybe).
- getRessources needs a valid Context to find the right res/ directory.

Two options:

- make this class a *subclass* of one of your activities and just try again.
- Pass the Context as an argument of the method that contains line 26.

Namely:

```
public void myMethod(Context cxt){
   String extStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
   String AudioRecorderDir=cxt.getResources().getString(R.string.fAudioRecorderDir);
   Log.d("SanityCheck","extStorage: "+extStorage+" audioRecoderDir: "+AudioRecorderDir);
   String homeDir=extStorage+"/"+AudioRecorderDir+"/";
   //etc
}
```

From your activity just call it so:

```
myObj.myMethod(this);
```

Comment: @user978879 did you try my solution?